# How to create a multiple folder in a single folder

Tags: python

**Create a multiple folder in a single folder.** as I want to create multiple folder

```
import os
def folder_Structure():
 folder = "A"
 folder1 = "A1"
 folder_name = "A2"
 root = "."
 path = f"{root}/{folder}/{folder1}/{folder_name}"
 print(path)
 os.makedirs(path)

 folder_name1 = "B"
 folder_name2 = "A"
 folder_name3 = "B"
 folder_name4 = "c"
 root = "."
 print(path)
 os.makedirs(path)
folder_Structure()
```

Comment: what's the issue that you're facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
folder = "Q"
folder1 = "E"
folder_name = "SS"
root = "."
path = f"{root}/{folder}/{folder1}/{folder_name}"
os.makedirs(path)

folder_name1 = "01"
folder_name2 = "02"
folder_name3 = "03"
folder_name4 = "03"
path = f"{folder_name1}/{folder_name2}/{folder_name3}/{folder_name4}"
os.makedirs(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please include the below line after root = ".". Hope you will get your output

```
path = f"{folder_name1}/{folder_name2}/{folder_name3}/{folder_name4}"
```